# How do i read in a file with buffer reader but skip comments with java

Tags: java

I wrote a program that reads a file with buffer reader and stores data in a String variable. How can i modify it to make it skip single and multi-line comments?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class IfCounter 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // parameter the TA will pass in
        String fileName = args[0];

        // variable to keep track of number of if's
        int ifCount = 0;

        // create a new BufferReader
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader (fileName));
        String line  = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        // read from the text file
        while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(ls);
        }

        // create a new string with stringBuilder data
        String tempString = stringBuilder.toString();

        // create one last string to look for our valid if(s) in
        // with ALL whitespace removed
        String compareString = tempString.replaceAll("\\s","");

        // check for valid if(s)
        for (int i = 0; i < compareString.length(); i++)
        {
            if (compareString.charAt(i) == ';' || compareString.charAt(i) == '}' || compareString.charAt(i) == '{') // added opening "{" for nested ifs :)
            {
                i++;

                if (compareString.charAt(i) == 'i')
                {
                    i++;

                    if (compareString.charAt(i) == 'f')
                    {
                        i++;

                        if (compareString.charAt(i) == '(')
                            ifCount++;
                    } // end if
                } // end if
            } // end if

        } // end for

        // print the number of valid "if(s) with a new line after"
        System.out.println(ifCount + "\n");

    } // end main
} // end class
```

Comment: Uh, is this homework? If so, mark it as such. If not, what defines a "comment"?

Comment: Define a file type or specify what defines a comment. Comment indicators differ depending on the language/file format, e.g. REM, //, /* ... */, etc.

Comment: This is a difficult thing to account for. Consider the line `String s = "//"; // mean line` or `String /* comment // */ s = "/* //" //` So many special cases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      stringBuilder.append(line);
      stringBuilder.append(ls);
    }
```

to this:

```
    boolean multiLineComment = false;
    while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      if (!isLineAMultiLineCommentStart(line)) {
        multiLineComment = true;
      }

      if (multiLineComment) {
        if (!isLineAMultiLineCommentEnd(line)) {
          multiLineComment = false;
        }
      }

      if (!isLineAComment(line) && !multiLineComment) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
        stringBuilder.append(ls);
      }
    }
```

You'll need to create a boolean methods, `isLineAComment(String line)`, `isLineAMultiLineCommentStart`, and `isLineAMultiLineCommentEnd` but this should be easy for you to do.

Comment: This won't account for multi-line comments because isLineAComment won't necessarily have state. It could store it somewhere though.

Comment: @tjameson: see edit that was done before I saw your comment. :)

Comment: Yup for a handwritten parser it's usually the simplest to just write a `skipComment()` function as soon as you identify the start of one. Though that would obviously complicate matters somewhat

Comment: Well the `isLineAMultiLineCommentEnd` would still need to store state somewhere (at least "Are we currently in a multiline comment?") as far as I can see.

Comment: @Voo: yes, that's what the boolean variable, multiLineComment, is for.

Comment: @Hovercraft: You mean the local variable that isn't passed to the function? ;) I think I can see the logic you'd want to use.. seems still much more complex than just allowing the function to skip until the next non-comment line. Maybe that's just preference though, who knows.,

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't specify what the input language is, and without that it is not possible to give a complete answer.  (For instance, if the input language was Fortran IV, you would just look for a 'C' in column 6.  Does that answer satisfy you?)

The general answer is that *accurate* comment stripping usually requires you to implement (at least) a partial lexical analyzer for the input language.  For instance, in Java accurate comment stripping needs to deal with:

- `//` comments in the middle of a line
- `/* ... */` comments spanning multiple lines
- comments where the `/` or `*` characters are expressed as Unicode escapes
- `//` or `/*` or `*/` embedded in string literals

There quite a lot to get right there ...

---

If you are actually attempting to do this to analyze Java source code, a better idea would be to use an existing Java parser / AST analysis framework.  For instance, PMD has a nice framework for doing this kind of thing ... and I'm sure that there are other alternatives.

Comment: +1 for mentioning lexical analysis. You really should come back to your books, josh, and read up on it. As for AST, this is created in a later phase of compilation, after lexems (so comments, too) are already recognized.